# Postgresql with Sworm in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm

I did API in nodejs where I connect to MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle and PostgreSQL, so I am using Sworm ORM to make that.

All works fine, except with PostgreSQL because I obtain response: **pg.connect is not a function**

My config is:

```
import Sworm from 'sworm'

const dbExtern = Sworm.db()
await dbExtern.connect({
          config: {
            database,
            host,
            password,
            pool: true,
            user
          },
          driver: 'pg'
        })
```

My package.json is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "mssql": "6.0.1",
    "mysql": "2.17.1",
    "oracledb": "4.1.0",
    "pg": "7.14.0"
}
```

My version node is: v12.13.1

I read that it happend because pg.connect in version 7 is deprecated, so it should to be with  pg.pool:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var pool = new pg.Pool() 
pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
  client.query(/* etc, etc */)
  done()
})
pool.end()
```

But, I didn't use 'pg' but 'Sworm', please, I need to stay with versions updated, any suggestion?